# Allowed VCard elements

Tags: vcf-vcard

I create VCards (.vcf-files) in some apps of mine. Now a customer needs to add a private mobile and a business mobile number to a vcard.

I have tried to add two times the same attribute to the vcard (TEL;CELL;VOICE) but this seems not to be supported (at least outlook only takes the first instance).

Is there a up-to-date description of all fields I can add into vcards and is there a description on what is allowed and what are donts.

If I search the web, I find a lot of information, but the most of it is very old and it seems that the different clients only support a subset of attributes.

Comment: vCard references: http://www.imc.org/pdi/

Comment: and specifications: http://www.imc.org/pdi/pdiproddev.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the version of vCard that Outlook supports vs. the version to which you are coding.

I think that Outlook supports only vCard ver 2.x and perhaps that version does not support what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the [cardme](https://github.com/george-haddad/cardme) project will do your happiness.
Many others projects are existing, but these one was the best to my point of view.